# HTML5 cache manifest

Tags: android, caching, webview

is there a way using the CACHE MANIFEST for html5 to just embed the files in an Android project (maybe in the assets folder) instead of the manifest file being on a server? I would like all files to be embedded in the Android project.

Right now I have an html5 document opening in webView that plays some mp3 links...problem is they redownload everytime i play them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way using the CACHE MANIFEST for html5 to just embed the files in an Android project (maybe in the assets folder) instead of the manifest file being on a server?

No, but you can use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) to convert an HTML5 application into an APK file.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it is an existing Android Project and trying to work with HTML5 audio tags in a webview...my limited coding knowledge is getting me caught up trying to use JavascriptInterface to call mediaplayer as well:( thanks for any more insight